# Run XNA 4.0 game on other machines

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I checked here: [How do I get an XNA 4.0 game to run on other machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434191/how-do-i-get-an-xna-4-0-game-to-run-on-other-machines), but there's no real solution in it.

I created a completely empty XNA4.0 project, selected Release and compiled it, rar'd up the Release folder and sent it to a non-development PC. Got an Appcrash generic error.

Its probably something standard I'm doing wrong, but no idea what..
Can confirm that both .NET4.0, XNA Redist 4.0 and DirectX are installed on the other machine.

UPDATE: The empty 'new game' loads now, but I have made a program or six over the last years, each of which doesn't run on the other machine. Could someone perhaps link me to 'proper' referencing, assemblies, and such? Google dropped those words more than once in combination with my problem.

UPDATE: I asked a friend to test on his PC, at first, same error, but he forgot to install the XNA 4.0 redist. After that, my files were running fine on his pc. Still, they're not working on my own non-development machine, for some reason. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions, now that I know its local I can probably fix it myself. Suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there the Dot-Net 4.0 and XNA 4.0 framework installed?

Comment: .NET installed. Is the XNA4.0 framework also required on target machine? I'll give it a quick check.

-- edited main answer, all is present.

Comment: Yes - but just the Redistributable one - not the one you have installed for visual studio ;)

Answer (score 2):

The end-user needs to have .NET 4.0, the [XNA 4.0 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914) (not the full game studio), and DirectX installed.

Comment: Edited main question, all three are installed.

Comment: If you are using XNA 4 Refresh, make sure the XNA 4 Refresh Redistributable. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27598)

Comment: I am not using the XNA4 Refresh version, but was worth a shot.

Comment: @Taelia also make sure its the latest DirectX. Download and install the lastest DirectX version to be sure, I've run into problems like that before.

Answer (score 0):

Choose to publish the project and you will get an installer that check and install required libraries for you...